# What does this structure mean: "to be had"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> There was satisfaction **to be had** in reversing viewpoints.

What does **to be had** mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 18):

Consider these two sentences:

> the sailor **loves** the girl
>  
>   the girl **is loved**.

The first sentence is called **active voice**- it says **who** did **what** to **whom**. The second sentence is **passive voice**: note that it doesn't say **who** is doing something: sometimes this is useful if we don't know, or don't care, or don't want to say **who** did something.

Moving on to your sentence:

> You can **have** satisfaction in reversing viewpoints
>   Satisfaction can **be had** in reversing viewpoints.

The first of these sentences is an active voice version that expresses the same idea as the one in your question. The second sentence is in passive voice: it eliminates the need to say **you**, and so it suggests that anybody can have this satisfaction. From here it's a small step, just a matter of literary style, to your sentence:

> There was satisfaction **to be had** in reversing viewpoints

Answer (score 0):

JavaLatte has [a good explanation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/100353/10238) of how to reorder the sentence, making it active voice, in order to understand it a different way.

Beside reordering, you could also try replacing the phrase "to be had" with an equivalent word: "available".

> There was satisfaction available in reversing viewpoints.

By reversing viewpoints, you can get satisfaction. There is some satisfaction available for you to have.